Role Protection in ReactJS tsx
I asked similar question on stackoverflow, but here I am trying to get a code review. I never write a production code for frontend part, so I need some sight from the side.
I am trying to implement role-based protection in ReactJS (typescript) application.
I have searched the web for this topic, there are many tutorials and confusions between typescript version, V6 react-router-dom (I am using V6) and so on.
I have build the basic functionality and this code is working:
Here is my App.tsx
import { useRef } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AboutPrograms from './components/landing/AboutPrograms/AboutPrograms';
import SignIn from './components/landing/SignIn/SignIn';
import Header from './components/landing/Header/Header';
// ...
import { AuthProvider } from './components/personal_account/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import PrivateWrapper from './components/personal_account/PrivateWrapper/PrivateWrapper';
import MainStudentPage from './components/personal_account/StudentPage/MainStudentPage/MainStudentPage';
import MainTeacherPage from './components/personal_account/TeacherPage/MainTeacherPage/MainTeacherPage';

function App() {
  const admissionFormRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <>
                  <Header />
                  <AboutPrograms />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route path="/log_in" element={<SignIn />} />
            <Route
              path="/student"
              element={
                <PrivateWrapper>
                  <MainStudentPage />
                </PrivateWrapper>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/teacher"
              element={
                <PrivateWrapper>
                  <MainTeacherPage />
                </PrivateWrapper>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

This is my AuthProvider:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  ReactNode,
  FC,
} from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// TODO: two more interfaces
interface User {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
}

interface AuthContextProps {
  user: User | null;
  login: (userData: User) => void;
  logout: () => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = (userData: User) => {
    setUser(userData);
    localStorage.setItem('role', userData.name);
    if (userData.role === 'student') {
      navigate('/student');
    }
    if (userData.role === 'teacher') {
      navigate('/teacher');
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('role');
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = (): AuthContextProps => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

And this is my SignIn.tsx element
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAuth } from '../../personal_account/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import './SignIn.css';

const SignIn = () => {
  const [loginFrom, setLoginForm] = useState('');
  const [passwordForm, setPasswordForm] = useState('');

  const { login } = useAuth();

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    login({ name: loginFrom, password: passwordForm, role: loginFrom });
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const role = localStorage.getItem('role');
    if (role === 'student') {
      navigate('/student');
    }
    if (role === 'teacher') {
      navigate('/teacher');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="signin__general">
        <div className="signin__form-container">
          <h2 className="signin__title"> Вход в ЛК &#128526; </h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="signin__form">
            <div className="signin__input-group">
              <label htmlFor="login" className="signin__label">
                Логин
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="login"
                value={loginFrom}
                onChange={(e) => setLoginForm(e.target.value)}
                className="signin__input"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="signin__input-group">
              <label htmlFor="password" className="signin__label">
                Пароль
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                value={passwordForm}
                onChange={(e) => setPasswordForm(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="signin__button">
              Войти
            </button>
            <p className="signin__info">
              Пока вход не доступен, но мы скоро вернёмся !{' '}
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignIn;

And finally PrivateWrapper.tsx:
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAuth } from '../AuthContext/AuthContext';

const PrivateWrapper = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const storedRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
  if (storedRole) {
    return storedRole ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
  return auth?.user ? children : <Navigate to="/log_in" replace />;
};

export default PrivateWrapper;

As I said it is working okay.
My first question is the most crucial for me. I am sure in backend part of my application. I will send an auth request and will get an access_token with valuable payload. I have intention to store insensible data in localStorage, but every authenticated request to backend API will be used with this access token.
Is it okay to store part of user data in localStorage for quick access ? For instance my decision to store the role in localStorage is okay? Or should I store it in encrypted access token?
My second question is, how do I implement role-based access?
I need the following behaviour - if user is authenticated and it is student - he must have access only to MainStudentPage element.
If user is authenticated and it is teacher - he must have access only to MainTeacherPage element.
I could not find the way to do it without using redux and with V6 react-router-dom.
On which level should I make this check? On the level of App.tsx or somewhere in PrivateWrapper.tsx?

"how do I implement role-based access?" Isn't a question we can answer. Please can you remove the question, and accompanying information, from your post.

By role-based access I mean protecting the routes /student and /teacher and basically nothing more. And besides that I want to get a review for my code..
